# How do you run a function on a specific $location.url()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change *some* of the content of the page when the user clicks to a new view and location /view. I say *some* because if I were changing *all* of the content I would know to use `routeProvider` and load a new template.

So, when $location.url() changes to 'dash/new' how can I get the below function to work?

```
$scope.currentRoute = $location.url();

if currentRoute == 'dash/my' {
    console.log('go!')
}
```

Is it bad to change things based on $location.url() in Angular JS? [The documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) says it's  to 'watch and observe' but if you can't take action based on it then what's the alternative?

Comment: _why_ can't you take action when watching on $location.url?

Comment: I thought you can only watch it change, not run function on a specific URL? If not, would like to see an example

Answer (score 1):

Look at `$route` [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route). It has events like `$routeChangeStart` and `$routeChangeSuccess` which you can use. Subscribe to these events in your controller and perform the necessary logic.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you:

```
 $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
                // no logged user, we should be going to #login
                if (next.$$route.originalPath == "/login") {
                   // say hello when start change view to #login                    
               } 

        });
```

Maybe would be fine if you use this at app.run method.
If you want to handle after routeChanges, $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the angular docs on [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)?

here's an example right from the main page

```
scope.$watch('name', function() {
 scope.greeting = scope.salutation + ' ' + scope.name + '!';
}); // initialize the watch
```

why can't you do that on $location.url?